# Can't break into AutoMapper Map if TSource is Nullable<DateTime>

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda, automapper, nullable

I have a AutoMapper Map that's defined like this

```
CreateMap<DateTime?, DateString>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.HasValue ? src.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : String.Empty));
```

`DateString` is defined as such

```
public class DateString
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

The `Value` property is a `String` that represents a date in the format `yyyymmdd` so to accommodate this expected format, I convert my dates represented as `DateTime` types to a `String` in this format.

The map above is triggered from another map that is defined like so

```
CreateMap<DateTimeDetails, PickupDetails>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.time, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

The `DateTimeDetails` and `PickupDetails` classes are defined as

```
public class DateTimeDetails
{
    public Nullable<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public String Time { get; set; }
    public Int32 TimeZoneOffset { get; set; }
}

public class PickupDetails
{
    public TimeString time { get; set; }
    public DateString date { get; set; }
}
```

So the general flow is this:

When `DateTimeDetails` is converted to `PickupDetails`, properties `PickupDetails.date` and `DateTimeDetails.Date` match up automatically without the use of a `.ForMember()` and `.MapFrom()` and trigger the `DateTime? -> DateString` map.

Wherein the `DateString.Value` property is set to `yyyymmdd` or `String.Empty` based on if the `Nullable<DateTime>` source object has a value or not.

The problem I'm having is that if I make `TSource` for my `DateTime? -> DateString` map nullable with either `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`, AutoMapper won't recognize the `<TSource, TDestination>` signature and map the `PickupDetails.date` property. It will throw the error

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
DateTimeDetails -> PickupDetails

Type Map configuration:
DateTimeDetails -> PickupDetails

Property:
date
```

If I make my map something more explicit like

```
CreateMap<DateTime?, DateString>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src =>
    {
        if (src.HasValue)
        {
            return src.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }));
```

And attempt to break into the logic for the resolver I won't hit any breakpoint placed anywhere within the resolver.

The only way I can get it to work is if I change `TSource` to a non-nullable `DateTime` type and implement a `!= null` check instead of a `Nullable<DateTime>.HasValue` check in the ternary statement for the return like so

```
CreateMap<DateTime, DateString>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src != null ? src.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : String.Empty));
```

In this format AutoMapper will recognize the `<TSource, TDestination>` signature and automatically map the `PickupDetails.date` from the `DateTimeDetails -> PickupDetails` map.

I can't see where I'm going wrong and why the `TSource` for my `DateTime? -> DateString` map cannot be `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?` and has to be non-nullable `DateTime`

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H3hOFc) is a repo for the problem. This online compiler can't run AutoMapper V7.0.1 so V6.2.2 is what is being used and the behaviour with 6.2.2 is still incorrect, but not the same as what I'm experiencing in 7.0.1 that I have explained above in this post.

### **EDIT 1: **

With Lucian Bargaoanu's help I've figured out more about what is happening with this mapping. The following are the execution plans for the same map with the same `.ForMember()` statement, the only thing that's changed is the `TSource`

[image: AutoMapper Execution Plans]

For the map using a `Nullable<DateTime>` `TSource` there is an if-else block executed that checks against the `$src` property. If null it returns not a `new` instance of the `TDestination` class, just a pointer to it, resulting in the `destObj.date` property not being set equal to an empty instance of its class type which would have it contain a `.Value` property for a full access path of `destObj.date.Value`, `destObj.date` is just set to null.

What I'm unsure of is if this is a .Net Core framework behaviour that inserts this `if($src == null)` check if a lambda is working with a `Nullable<T>` variable, or if AutoMapper is adding it. Because as you can see below for the execution plan on the right side of the image above, I am attempting to handle the `$src == null` scenario myself. But as of right now I will never get there.

I'm also not sure what roll the `$typeMapDestination` variable plays in the whole of AutoMapper, but right now I get a `Error mapping types.` error for my `CreateMap<Nullable<DateTime>, DateString>()` map.

I was thinking it might be because the `if($src == null)` block stops the `$typeMapDestination` variable from being manipulated/returned and so the destination property designated in the `.ForMemeber()` is never actually, "mapped" so an error is thrown.

One more behaviour worth noting is for the non-nullable `DateTime -> DateString` map, if it is sent a null value, despite the following code block

```
$resolvedValue = .Try {
    .If($src != null) {
        .Call $src.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    } .Else {
        System.String.Empty
    }
} .Catch(System.NullReferenceException) {
    .Default(System.String)
} .Catch(System.ArgumentNullException) {
    .Default(System.String)
};
```

something is causing that try to fail and drop to one of the two catch blocks below. The `else { System.String.Empty }` portion of the if/else block will not trigger. And `destObj.date` will be equal to null instead of a new instance of `DateString` with a `.Value` property of `""`.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I added a link to a repo that will replicate the problem if run with AutoMapper V7.0.1

Comment: Try the [MyGet](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/The-MyGet-build.html) build. And check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Instead of checking for null, check for DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I've added an edit with more information I've gathered using the MyGet build and your advice regarding execution plans.

I also tried checking against MinValue like you mentioned via src > DateTime.MinValue, src.Value > DateTime.MinValue, I have also tried src.HasValue, src.Value != null, and src != null for the Nullable<DateTime> -> DateString map with no luck. 

I've also tried src > DateTime.MinValue and src != null for the DateTime->DateString map, and neither would access the second half of the ternary statement responsible for setting destObj.date to String.Empty.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/82213f93d73642e0c24b515c94914129

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I was unaware of the .ConvertUsing() method! Implementing that for my DateTime? map finally results in my destObj.date prop having a .Value of String.Empty! For some reason when I do provide a DateTime I get a unmapped property error in AutoMapper 7.0.1, but not in .Net Fiddler with AutoMapper V6.2.2, lol. But it was a simple fix, I added a second non-nullable DateTime map for when the DateTime? src.Date prop has a value. Maybe the property when it has a value, is getting cast before a Map is searched for? Regardless, thank you so much!

Comment: I get no error with the MyGet build. Did you set CreateMissingTypeMaps to false?